# How to set executable file, which will run at startup, when the Azure starting up a new instance of virtual machine?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

I have virtual machine which will be automatically scaled in Azure cloud. And application, which must run, when instance will complete loading. How can I do this?

Comment: On what operating system does your app run ?

Comment: Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter from Azure gallery.

Comment: Then do the following links help ? http://serverfault.com/questions/583517/start-program-on-computer-startup-when-nobody-is-logged-on-and-show-the-window-w       http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/1043-71-program-startup-windows-server-2012